# Read a v-textarea line by line using JavaScript in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-textarea with the following properties:

```
                      <v-textarea
                      v-model="pmidInput"                         
                      name="input-PMID"                         
                      label="PMID Area"
                      value
                      hint="11111111,2222222,33333333"
                    ></v-textarea>
```

I need to be able to read the textarea line by line so if a person puts in line feeds I can replace them with a comma and end up with a comma separated string.

I tried to use

```
 let splitLines = this.pmidInput.split(" ");
```

to put each line into an array but it does not seem to identify the white space, it sees the value fine just not the white space.  Is there a way that would work?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed:

```
 let splitLines = this.pmidInput.split("\n");
```